# Blazor host on IIS shows blank page

Tags: iis, blazor, blazor-server-side, iis-express

I created a Blazor Server Project which runs well from Visual Studio, i tried hosting same app on IIS installed Runtime and Hosting Bundle to achieve this. Also, i created site and pointed to the published files. When i run the app on the browser, it shows me a blank page without any error.

Please what could i be doing wrong?

Comment: Did you enebale WebSockets on iss ? if not : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-5.0#enabling-websockets-on-iis

Comment: No i did not enable any web sockets. Like i mentioned the app runs from visual studio using iss express so i just built, published and hosted in IIS

Comment: Please inspect the received data using the webbrowser development tools. What did you receive? Any http responses? Console errors? etc.

Comment: make sure you have installed the correct version of the runtime. try to set the application pool to no managed code. [image](https://i.imgur.com/BvkH3J0.png). add this code in web.config file:`<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
</system.webServer>`

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue today...
I accidentally deleted an import in _Host.cshtml. Unfortunately, this import was used in a string, so no error could be generated. After fixing this all worked fine again.

Answer (score -1):

IIS requires a web.config that isn't created with a normal debug/release build, which is why you are just getting a white screen.

You can use this walkthrough to learn how to publish the website for IIS [publish a blazor server application to iis](https://executecommands.com/publish-a-blazor-server-application-to-iis/)

Alternatively, you could build your own web.config - but I wouldn't recommend it.